# Where / how is the best way / location to display a menu under a menu

Tags: website-design, gui-design, user-behavior, menu

Upon login I have a menu with options and underneath it another menu ("what to do with those") [image]

What will be the best practice in this scenario to display this menu and buttons from a UI perspective? or how should I change it to look better?

Comment: Hi @Athanatos!  Welcome to the UX Stack Exchange.  Can you provide some more context?  Who are your users?  What are the menus used for?  At the moment, it looks like the second level ("Popular," etc.) are filters, not menus.

Comment: Hi @3nafish yes you are right there are filters really, the menu above the filters is used to take the users to different pages and the filters (popular etc to filter items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll field the "location" question. [Research by Kingsburg](http://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3588&context=etd_theses) ([summarized](http://www.usability.gov/get-involved/blog/2006/04/left-navigation-is-best.html)), suggests you get the best user performance and user satisfaction if the first (top-level) menu is on the left, the second menu is on the top, rather than the other way around, or both being on top. I'd think the results would apply to cases like yours when the second menu is a filter.